# Create a prometheus-operator `PrometheusRule` (CRD) from a raw Prometheus rule file?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

A Prometheus rules file like this:

```
groups:
- name: ./example.rules
  rules:
  - alert: ExampleAlert
    expr: vector(1)
```

The Kubernetes prometheus-operator requires an extra layer of yaml configuration data and looks like this:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    prometheus: example
    role: alert-rules
  name: prometheus-example-rules
spec:
  groups:
  - name: ./example.rules
    rules:
    - alert: ExampleAlert
      expr: vector(1)
```

With files using the former, raw Prometheus rule format, I can use Prometheus `promtool` to run unit tests. (see link 3 below)

With files using the latter, extended PrometheusRule format, I can use `kubectl apply -f prometheus_rule_file.yaml` to load the rules into my prometheus-operator installation.

I want to write and maintain rules in one of these file formats and be able to use the same rule file both with promtool's unit test system and to load the same rule into a prometheus-operator installation. I don't see an easy way to do this.

Is there a way I can have a rule using the raw Prometheus rule format and load it into a prometheus-operator PrometheusRule without maintaining a separate redundant yaml file and without writing a customized tool to convert it?

1. https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/
2. https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/alerting.md
3. https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/unit_testing_rules/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I got this to work with **helm** is to create a separate chart and put rules files along with the chart files. This means you need to deploy them independently and perhaps that's what you intend.

Steps

1. Create a helm chart: `helm create prometheus-rules`
2. Create `rules` directory and put prometheus rule files in that directory.
3. Delete all unnecessary yaml files in `templates/` directory
4. Create a new template file `templates/prometheus-rules.yaml`
5. Insert example below:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: List
    items:
    {{- $root := .Files }}
    {{- range $path, $bytes := $root.Glob "rules/**.yaml" }}
      - apiVersion: "monitoring.coreos.com/v1"
        kind: PrometheusRule
        metadata:
          name: prometheus-rules-{{ $path | base }}
          labels:
            app: prometheus-operator
        spec:
          groups:
    {{ $root.Get $path | indent 8 }}
    {{- end}}
```

---

**NOTE**: one tricky thing is to watch out for `prometheus.prometheusSpec.ruleSelectorNilUsesHelmValues` value when installing the prometheus-operator chart. It will only load rules which have the same labels as were installed during prometheus-operator. You can get around that by setting it to false when installing prometheus-operator. See [ruleSelector logic](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/templates/prometheus/prometheus.yaml#L116) for more details.

Comment: @PathSeeker Could you please share a full sample helm alert file.

Comment: @bibincatchme Sure, you can see my full example here: https://github.com/pesarkhobeee/The-EKS-the-Prometheus-and-the-Wardrobe/blob/master/monitoring.sh

Comment: This yaml file is throwing me error ,"Error: YAML parse error on prometheus-custom-rules/templates/prometheus-rules.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: could not find expected ':'"

Comment: @Pavel, I just want to mention that your "Note" up there _finally_ solve an issue I have been looking at trying to implement custom PrometheusRules for the *last 3 hours*. THANK YOU.

Comment: @pavel while reading rule files it gives error undefined variable $value, how to get around that

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking at this exact situation for myself. I think I will go a slightly different route.

The plan is to only have `PrometheusRule` custom resources and then use `yq` to pass the "raw" Prometheus rules to `promtool` like this.

```
$ promtool check rules <(cat my_prometheusrule.yaml | yq '.spec')
Checking /dev/fd/11
  SUCCESS: 5 rules found
```

Comment: quite helpful to use in CI